# Celery and mysql connections

Tags: python, mysql, celery

What is the appropriate way to handle mysql connections when multiple celery tasks read and write to the same database?
Pooling ? If so, is there support for it in mysqldb for python?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe pooling is the right option. You can use `SQLAlchemy` ORM which has pooling support or  pooling can be supported by this [package](https://code.google.com/p/pysqlpool/)

Comment: pysqlpool seems to do the job, i'll give it a go. Thanks!